# Why Output is like this in visual studio 2012

Tags: c

IN Visual studio 2012, if run the below code i getting the output as mentioned below

```
typedef unsigned short      u16;
typedef unsigned long long      u64;
int main()
{
    u16 i = 10;
    u64 j = 1000;
    printf("i= %d, j= %lu\n", i, j);
    printf("j= %lu, i= %d\n", j, i);
    getchar();
}

output:
i = 10, j = 1000
j = 1000, i = 0
```

//Why?

Comment: Use `%llu` for `unsigned long long`.

Comment: I assume you're asking why `i` changes from `10` to `0`? Looks like a bug. Neither Clang nor GCC exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Using MSVC mode [here](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual), I note that making the switch from `%lu` to `%llu` fixes the output. I'm not sure why the format specifier should affect how `i` is printed, though.

Comment: Because it affects how many bytes `printf()` uses in the argument list to process the first format option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass an [`unsigned long long`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type) (`j`) to `printf()` (8 bytes). But, because of the incorrect format specifier (`%lu` should be [`%llu`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)), `printf()` reads only half of them (the least significant 4 bytes). The other 4 bytes are interpreted by `printf()` for `%d` (instead of `i` which is ignored). All 4 most significant bytes of `1000` are `0`.

Because of the mismatch between the number of bytes of the value and its specifier, it is [`Undefined Behaviour`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The first `printf()` works fine because it just happens that the 4 bytes of `j` read by `printf()` are the least significant bytes. Put a number greater than `2^32` in `j` and you'll get wrong results on both calls of `printf()`.